# Comparing Dates on Google Sheets with Google Apps Scripts is Returning Inaccurate Boolean Values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My Google Sheets spreadsheet has a list of appointments that I am trying to compare with tomorrow's date (so that I can send a reminder the day before). My current code is returning true on certain dates that aren't on the spreadsheet. We have no appointments on Sundays and I am currently testing this on a Saturday but still receiving some true values. I searched the spreadsheet thoroughly for a possible booking mistake but there are none. I did notice, however, that when it looks for the date 4:24:2016 (which is tomorrow) it will return true on 4:14:2016 dates. I am pretty much stumped at this point.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var apptDates = sheet.getRange(2, 32, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i <= apptDates.length; i++) {
    var apptDate = new Date(apptDates[i][0]);
    apptDate = apptDate.addHours(74);

    function dayAway(date, day) {
      return new Date(date.getTime() + day * (24 * 3600 * 1000));
    }
    Logger.log(apptDate >= dayAway(new Date(), 1));
  }
}
```

Comment: Try taking out the utilities.formatDate part. Creating a Date obj with the cell value should be sufficient enough to compare dates.

Comment: @Gerneio I removed the utilities.formatDate but now it is continuously returning false. When I Logged the results of both dates, each date has a contradicting timestamp so that was why I was trying to format it without times. Is there a way to compare dates without having to compare the times as well?

Comment: How much of a contradiction?

Comment: When I log dayAway(): [16-04-23 10:18:09:841 PDT] Tue Apr 26 12:18:09 GMT-05:00 2016
When I log apptDate : [16-04-23 10:18:09:842 PDT] Tue Apr 26 00:00:00 GMT-05:00 2016

Comment: You changed it to:      var apptDate = new Date(apptDates[i][0]);        Right?

Comment: Yep. the dayAway function is just placing the time that function is initiating. The dates it is comparing has midnight 00:00:00 for all of them.

Comment: Not sure why there is such a large gap, however simply doing something like this should correct it: apptDate = apptDate.addHours(74); this should be called after the initial value is assigned.

Comment: Also use >= on that last part, this'll give us an idea of where we stand at the momment. Also update your current code so that I can see what you got.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot find function addHours in object Tue Dec 29 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST).

Comment: Sorry, try this : apptDate = apptDate.setHours(apptDate.getHours() + 74);

Comment: This is returning an even larger number of trues for tomorrow. I also tested it with different numbers of days away and it is still coming back inaccurate. Can I ask, why did you want to add 74 hours? Just trying to understand the reasoning.

Comment: Difference between the day you need and the day you received in the logger was 74 hours worth. (4/26/16 12:18:09 - 4/23/16 10:18:09). What you need to check now is if all the true values dates are greater than or equal to tomorrow's date. So essentially dates of appointments in the future will appear, no appointment dates for today of the past should show. Next we'll add the other end of the bound

Comment: Okay I made an error while testing. I was changing the second argument of dayAway()  to different numbers to see its effects. My last log was 3 days. Sorry about that, I see that probably took us down a completely different path.

Comment: Haha I see now. Well were you able to confirm what i stated in my last question about future dates?

Comment: tbh, it's completely random. I have trues showing up from January all the way up to April. lol

Comment: Gahhhh.... If you want build a Google sheet, add some sample data similar to what you have in your sheet, and then make it public and share the link here and I'll get it working for you.

Comment: I will do that lol

Comment: Definitely know what you mean. And this is me trying to refactor from the original. Just to make it work for the time being I originally stringified the date, substr the two digits for the day, parsed it, added +1 and toString()ed it. but eventually I was comparing dates like 1/32/16 << HA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `new Date()` you get a full [JS Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) with **not only day, month and year** but also **hours minutes, seconds and milliseconds**.

That's why your comparison could not give results.
Simply set the unneeded values to `0` and it will work. I used `getTime()` to compare milliseconds but could have used `toString()` as well, only the date objects are not suitable to check equality.

The Logger is a great help to debug such things.

code :

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var apptDates = sheet.getRange(2,6, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < apptDates.length; i++) {
    var apptDate = new Date(apptDates[i][0]);
    Logger.log(apptDate.getTime()+'  ==?  '+dayAway(new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)), 1).getTime());
    Logger.log(apptDate.getTime() == dayAway(new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)), 1).getTime());
  }
}

function dayAway(date, day) {
  return new Date(date.getTime() + day * 24 * 3600 * 1000);
}
```

[image]  [image]